# How to manually commit offset in Spark Kafka direct streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I looked around hard but didn't find a satisfactory answer to this. Maybe I'm missing something. Please help.

We have a Spark streaming application consuming a Kafka topic, which needs to ensure end-to-end processing before advancing Kafka offsets, e.g. updating a database. This is much like building transaction support within the streaming system, and guaranteeing that each message is processed (transformed) and, more importantly, output.

I have read about Kafka DirectStreams. It says that for robust failure-recovery in DirectStreaming mode, Spark checkpointing should be enabled, which [stores the offsets along with the checkpoints](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$). But the offset management is done internally (setting Kafka config params like [`"auto.offset.reset", "auto.commit.enable", "auto.offset.interval.ms"`]). It does not speak of how (or if) we can customize committing offsets (once we've loaded a database, for e.g.). In other words, can we set `"auto.commit.enable"` to false and manage the offsets (not unlike a DB connection) ourselves?

Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#kafka-itself

Comment: Is there any python implementation available for the manual offset commit in pyspark. I am not able to find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The article below could be a good start to understand the approach.

[spark-kafka-achieving-zero-data-loss](http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/05/07/spark-kafka-achieving-zero-data-loss.html)

Further more,

The article suggests using zookeeper client directly, which can be replaced by something like KafkaSimpleConsumer also. The advantage of using Zookeper/KafkaSimpleConsumer is the monitoring tools that depend on Zookeper saved offset. Also the information can also be saved on HDFS or any other reliable service.

Comment: This is definitely a good read @Rakesh, Thanks! The article suggests an alternate approach where one does not still control the offsets (by way of  setting auto-commit to false). However, as I read this article I realized an important concept in eventually-consistent systems, that once you've got the message through your door, the service ensures its delivery. An I guess that's the only mechanism one can follow in my case also.

Answer (score 0):

If you check you logs you would see

```
2019-10-24 14:14:45 WARN  KafkaUtils:66 - overriding enable.auto.commit to false for executor
2019-10-24 14:14:45 WARN  KafkaUtils:66 - overriding auto.offset.reset to none for executor
2019-10-24 14:14:45 WARN  KafkaUtils:66 - overriding executor group.id to spark-executor-customer_pref_az_kafka_spout_stg_2
2019-10-24 14:14:45 WARN  KafkaUtils:66 - overriding receive.buffer.bytes to 65536 see KAFKA-3135
```

These properties are overridden by spark code.

In order to manually commit you could follow spark docs

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#kafka-itself

Comment: thanks for your comment. Actually this was done with an older version of Spark 1.3 where it was really tricky to implement. But with Spark 2.3 onwards this is really a breeze, so this question may not be as relevant now :)

Answer (score -1):

According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#kafka-itself
`enable.auto.commit` must be set to false and

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
  OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

  // some time later, after outputs have completed
  ((CanCommitOffsets) stream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
});
```