# Offset Management in spark streaming using kafkautils(Kafka-0.8)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am working on Manual Offset Management in Kafka using the **spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11**

> org.apache.spark
>         spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11
>         2.1.0

From Kafka-0-10 onwards the documentation says that we can commit the offsets using the below code.

```
OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
((CanCommitOffsets) stream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
```

But, I am unable to understand how to commit offsets using the kafka-0-8. I could get the offset ranges but could not see `CanCommitOffsets` API. It seems this has been introduced only from kafka-0-10.

I do not want to use the Zookeeper/HBase/Checkpoint to manage the offsets.

Comment: Kafka 0.8 is _really_ old. Is upgrading to a new version an option?

Comment: We are going to upgrade in another 3 months but the current development needs to continue using kafka 0.8.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635381/how-to-manually-commit-offset-in-spark-kafka-direct-streaming